# How to show errors in browser?

Tags: symfony, sylius, symfony3.x

I'm getting started with [Sylius](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius). Symfony version is 3.2.7. On some pages I have some errors. The pages show text:

> **Oops! An Error Occurred**
>
> The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
>
> Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

I want the errors to be displayed in browser, with full stacktrace.

I know I can see the error in `var/prod.log`, but it doesn't show the whole stacktrace, only the last frame. And seeing the error in browser would be more convenient: that's what I'm used to after a lot of working with Yii and Magento.

Is that possible with Symfony/Sylius?

Comment: its your development env? or prod? If dev env is set, probably its something with your webserver settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added /app_dev.php to the url to run the website in development environment, and there I can see the stack trace.

That is, https://[my_domain]/app_dev.php/[page] instead of https://[my_domain]/[page]

Answer (score 0):

By default Symfony show trace in dev environment. In prod environment it show simple error message. For running your project in dev you can use built-in PHP Web Server or [Web Server Bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/built_in_web_server.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use symfony installer app to serve request

Use `symfony serve --no-tls` in symfony folder.
It will show you requests and errors in red.